# Are Rte_Prm_Read and Rte_Prm_Write standard AUTOSAR functions?

Tags: autosar

While reading some AUTOSAR code, I came across the following functions: `Rte_Prm_Read_someParameter` and `Rte_Prm_Write_someParameter`. They were next to the standard `Rte_Prm_someParameter` function, and provided read and write access to the parameter in question.

I couldn't find any description in the standard AUTOSAR_SWS_RTE. From my understanding the `Rte_` namespace was reserved for standard AUTOSAR function so I was wondering is I missed their specifications or if they were provided as helpers.

Comment: I can see `Rte_Prm` in the specification but not Read and Write.Can you check those functions are internal functions(could be invoked from Rte_Prm) or check the Port names